# JSON deeper encoding

Tags: php, file, formatting, json

I have a couple of objects that are json-encoded, and I would like to write them to a json file. The data is gathered from facebook.
For example if I do

```
$myfile="testson.json";
$fileout=fopen($myfile,'w') or die("Fatal: Can't write to JSON file");
$friends = idx($facebook->api('/me/friends?limit=5000'), 'data', array());//gather data from facebook
fwrite($fileout,json_encode($friends));
```

I get something like this:
  [{"name":"xyz","id":"2342342"},{other entries alike}]

Or, for the same thing with likes:

```
 [{"category":"Musician\/band","name":"Jack Savoretti","id":"216730015024772","created_time":"2013-03-14T13:38:27+0000"},{other entries alike}]
```

Now what i would like to do would be to list each of them under some categories. For example

```
        ["Likes":[{"category":"Musician\/band","name":"Jack Savoretti","id":"216730015024772","created_time":"2013-03-14T13:38:27+0000"},
{other entries alike}],  
    "friends":[{"name":"xyz","id":"2342342"},{other entries alike}]]
```

How can I do this?
I am using php `json_encode`.

Comment: You create the data structure you want with (nested) arrays and then encode the top-level array as JSON. I assume you know how to work with arrays. If not: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php.

Comment: Good point. Sorry, i'm quite new to php, I'm not yet really into it. Thanks a lot